# How to pass two dimensional array from python to function written in c++ using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++

How to pass two dimensional array from python to function written in c++ using SWIG ? 
I know how to do it fo normal functions but getting problems when I try to pass 2D integer array . 
I am having C++ function which takes 2D integer array as input and returns integer.  I want to call this from python . 
Any help regarding this is appeciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251042/passing-python-array-to-c-function-with-swig

Comment: Thanks :) Thats exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Here's a current link to the docs for Arrays: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn26

Comment: Here's an interesting link for numpy [Numpy.i: a SWIG Interface File for NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/swig.interface-file.html)